# Making a string out of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have pandas DataFrame which looks like this:

```
 Name  Number    Description
 car   5         red
```

And I need to make a string out of it which looks like this:

```
"""Name: car

Number: 5 

Description: red"""
```

I'm a beginner and I really don't get how do I do it? I'll probably need to apply this to some similar DataFrames later.

Comment: What should be displayed if you have several entries in your dataframe?

Comment: Then I have to somehow print that info for only one row.
For example I have rows "car1", "car2", "car3". If user types "car1" I need to print car1 line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iterrows` to iterate over you dataframe rows, on each row you can then get the columns and print the result the way you want. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

dtf = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name": ["car", "other"],
    "Number": [5, 6],
    "Description": ["red", "green"]
})

def stringify_dataframe(dtf):
    text = ""
    for i, row in dtf.iterrows():
        for col in dtf.columns.values:
            text += f"{col}: {row[col]}\n"
        text += "\n"
    return text

s = stringify_dataframe(dtf)
```

Now `s` contains the following:

```py
>>> print(s)
Name: car
Number: 5
Description: red

Name: other
Number: 6
Description: green
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can I somehow put it in a string, so I can just use it as variable in different needs

Comment: Yes sure, I'll update my answer (do you need one string per entry or one big string?)

Comment: I need one big string

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a Dataframe is faster when using `apply`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name": ["car", "other"],
    "Number": [5, 6],
    "Description": ["red", "green"]
})

s = '\n'.join(
        df.apply(
            lambda row: 
            '\n'.join(f'{head}: {val}' for head, val in row.iteritems()),
            axis=1))
```

Of course, for this small data set a for loop is faster, but on my machine a data set with 10 rows was already processed faster.

Comment: ```for i in range (len (dtf)):
        print(f'{dtf.loc[i]}\n')``` or ```for row in dtf.to_string(index = False).split('\n'):
    print(row)``` may also be used but not what author has asked.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach,

```
import pandas as pd

dtf = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name": ["car", "other"],
    "Number": [5, 6],
    "Description": ["red", "green"]
})


for row_index in range(len(dtf)):
    for col in dtf.columns:
        print(f"{col}: {dtf.loc[row_index, col]}")
```

```
Name: car
Number: 5
Description: red
Name: other
Number: 6
Description: green

[Program finished]
```